# Replace and move from start to end of line (notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

I want to replace and move "Wooden wall" to "Wall of Wood"
I can replace "Wooden" for "of Wood" but I get: "of Wood Wall", "of Wood Window", "of Wood Door"
and I need to move "of Wood" to the end by hand.

I need to replace a lot of word I trying to it with note++ regular expression but I need help

Comment: If you want to have an answer to your question you need to explain what you are trying to do and at least show and example of the file how does it look like ? does oit have plenty of lines full of "Wooden wall" ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to capture the sequence of characters that immediately follows "wooden", and move it to the front by including a reference to it in the replacement string:

```
wooden\s+(\w+)
```

replace with

```
$1 of wood
```

The "magic" comes from the interaction of the regex, which has a *capturing group* (the part of the expression inside parentheses) and the replacement string, which uses `$1` that stands in for "whatever is captured by the first parenthesized block of the regex."